# Method to find a type of equation that can fit a particular shape?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, curves

I'm trying to find a mathematical expression for a function that can fit this kind of data:
[image]

I wonder if there is a better way to do it than the naive high-order polynomial fit.
It seems like there is a type of sinusoidal component on top of a parabola, however, the smearing of the sinusoidal component on the right side of the shape makes me question that hypothesis.

Comment: I wonder if your data contains seasonality, so the waviness shouldn't be part of the fit. Looks like a degree 2 polynomial would fit best in that case. You don't want to "overfit".

Comment: $y=\sin(x)+(\sin{2πx})$ You may be able to mess with this, but it might not work. A quadratic might work though you'll have to fit it if you want the peaks or troughs.